# How do I keep my quick fire+smoke going for the whole animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

The quick fire was working great on my animation, but when I did an open GL render(hope I said that right) after a few seconds the fire stopped moving and froze entirely with it’s motion. Is it because I haven’t baked it yet? Did this only happen because it was a gl render? Or is there some way to control how long this fire goes. I would upload the file but it’s too large for blender exchange. But if you feel you need it, to answer the question I cane sent it to an email via Sendspace.

Comment: Hi. You have mentioned some suggestions, please **try them first**. (A) Try baking it. (B) Try not using the opengl render, but cycles instead. | And there seems to be conflicting information. Does the fire look fine when played back in the viewport? How did you render and view the opengl render? Can you add a screenshot of your fire simulation settings and your render settings (especially start and end frames etc...)

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.